# ConcurrentModification Exception while Iterating

Tags: java, performance, loops, exception, concurrency

I have looked at other questions that deal with similar problems, but it seems that this particular case is rather unique.

The code below is supposed to go through a list of Events and put them in a map if their times overlap.

```
// identify events that occur at the same time
List<Event> remainingEvents = new LinkedList<>();
remainingEvents = Event.getAllEvents();

for (Event event1 : Event.getAllEvents()) {
    for (Event event2 : remainingEvents) {

        // check if it is the same event
        if (event1 == event2)
            continue;

        // check whether they overlap
        if (event1.overlapsWith(event2)) {
            simultEvents.put(event1, event2);
        }
    }

    // event1 is now exhausted
    remainingEvents.remove(event1);
}
```

Notice that I am modifying the `remainingEvents` list after the iteration is complete, not during. Therefore, I do  not understand why I am getting a **ConccurentModificationException**.

Elipse also tells me that the error occurs on this line:

```
 for (Event event1 : Event.getAllEvents()) {
```

which makes no sense since I am not modifying anything relating to it.

**Note that this is not a duplicate because I am not modifying the list until I am done Iterating with it (unlike other questions), and the error occurs on a line that has nothing to do with the removal**

Comment: Check your loop nesting.  You're removing elements unsafely in the outermost loop.

Comment: But when that removal occurs, the respective list is no longer being iterated upon. Also, Makoto, you should not be so careless when marking questions as duplicates.

Comment: `remainingEvents = Event.getAllEvents();` - both loops iterate over the same list.

Comment: You maybe need `remainingEvents = new LinkedList<>(Event.getAllEvents());` This creates a copy.

Comment: Yes that was the problem and the solution. Thank everyone but Makoto for contributing.